# Python Pandas Data Formatting: Difference in passing index and iloc

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

This is the sample data:

```
dict_country_gdp = pd.Series([52056.01781,40258.80862,40034.85063,39578.07441],
    index = ['Luxembourg','Norway', 'Japan', 'Switzerland'])
```

What is the difference between `dict_country_gdp[0]` and `dict_country_gdp.iloc[0]`?

While the result is the same, when to use which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are working with one dimensional series, [] or .iloc will give same results.

**ONE DIMENSIONAL SERIES:**

```
import pandas as pd

dict_country_gdp = pd.Series([52056.01781, 40258.80862,40034.85063,39578.07441])

dict_country_gdp

Out[]: 
0    52056.01781
1    40258.80862
2    40034.85063
3    39578.07441
dtype: float64

dict_country_gdp[0]
Out[]: 52056.017809999998

dict_country_gdp.iloc[0]
Out[]: 52056.017809999998
```

**MULTI-DIMENSIONAL SERIES:**

```
dict_country_gdp = pd.Series([52056.01781, 40258.80862,40034.85063,39578.07441],[52056.01781, 40258.80862,40034.85063,39578.07441])

dict_country_gdp 
Out[]: 
52056.01781    52056.01781
40258.80862    40258.80862
40034.85063    40034.85063
39578.07441    39578.07441
dtype: float64
```

Now in this scenario, you cannot access series using [] operator.

```
dict_country_gdp[0]
Out[]: KeyError: 0.0

dict_country_gdp.iloc[0]
Out[]: 52056.017809999998
```

iloc provides more control while accessing multidimensional series:

```
dict_country_gdp[0:2]
Out[]: Series([], dtype: float64)

dict_country_gdp.iloc[0:2]
Out[]: 
52056.01781    52056.01781
40258.80862    40258.80862
dtype: float64
```

[Documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-integer) states:

.iloc is primarily integer position based (from 0 to length-1 of the axis), but may also be used with a boolean array. .iloc will raise IndexError if a requested indexer is out-of-bounds, except slice indexers which allow out-of-bounds indexing. (this conforms with python/numpy slice semantics). Allowed inputs are:

- An integer e.g. 5
- A list or array of integers [4, 3, 0]
- A slice object with ints 1:7
- A boolean array
- A callable function with one argument (the calling **Series, DataFrame
  or Panel**) and that returns valid output for indexing (one of the
  above)

This is why one cannot use [] operator with dataframe objects. Only iloc can be used when it comes to dataframes and multidimensional series.